# How to always place pseudo element after parent and not child?

Tags: html, less

What I am trying to achieve is to always display the star after the label's first child.

```
<label for="input-1" class="required">
   <span>
    Text
   </span>
  <span class="tooltip">
   <i class="icon"></i>
  <span class="message top">Tooltip on the top, with a very long message.</span>
 </span>
</label>

  &.required:after {
    content: '*';
    color: @link-blue;
    margin-left: 4px;

    &:first-child:after {
      content: '*';
    }

  }
```

The star in this case is after the icon. How can I force it to be always after the first child, which is the label text in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the pseudo on its first child (`.required > *:first-child`) instead of itself. What you want would be:

```less
&.required {
    > *:first-child::after {
        content: '*';
        color: @link-blue;
        margin-left: 4px;
    }
}
```

```css
.required > *:first-child::after {
  content: "*";
  margin-left: 4px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="input-1" class="required">
    <span>Text</span>
    <span class="tooltip">
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <span class="message top">Tooltip on the top, with a very long message.</span>
    </span>
</label>
```

### Edit

If you want to add asterisk for both of the scenarios that `label` with or without child elements, there are several solutions.

The first one is recommended, but you need to add an additional class to `label`s that have a tooltip(in this case `.has-tooltip`), so you can distinguish both scenarios and assign the `::before` correspondingly (since `:has` hasn't been widely supported yet).

```css
.required.has-tooltip > *:first-child::after, 
.required:not(.has-tooltip)::after {
  content: "*";
  margin-left: 4px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="input-1" class="required has-tooltip">
    <span>Text</span>
    <span class="tooltip">
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <span class="message top">Tooltip on the top, with a very long message.</span>
    </span>
</label>

<br />

<label for="input-1" class="required">Text</label>
```

The second one doesn't require any HTML modification, but it changes the `display` of your label and manipulates the position of elements through `order`. You may try it and see if it has any side-effects to your layout.

```css
.required {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.required::after {
  content: "*";
  margin-left: 4px;
  color: red;
}

.required > *:not(:first-child) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<label for="input-1" class="required">
    <span>Text</span>
    <span class="tooltip">
        <i class="icon"></i>
        <span class="message top">Tooltip on the top, with a very long message.</span>
    </span>
</label>

<br />

<label for="input-1" class="required">Text</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, I realised I wasn't clear enough. The problem is that with this approach I'm not getting any star if there's no icon, only text. I want to cover both cases. So in case there's only one child I still want to be able to have the required start. In case there's an icon, or another element, I want the start right after the first child.

Comment: @ag_ns994 Hello, I updated the answer, see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second solution won't work, since it does affect the layout. The problem with the other one, is that I don't necessarily want to introduce another class, like has-tooltip and I was wondering if there's a workaround